# When do you use a dot after self

Tags: objective-c

To my understand self refers to the current class and when i use a dot after self is to use one of its properties. In the code here there's a use in `self.popOperand` that i don't understand if popOpernad is not a property. Another thing i don't understand is why 
`[self pushOperand:result];` works and `[self.pushOperand:result];` doesn't.

```
#import "Calcbrain.h"
@interface Calcbrain()

@property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *operandStack;


@end


@implementation Calcbrain
@synthesize operandStack  = _operandStack;

-(NSMutableArray *) operandStack
{
    if(_operandStack == nil) _operandStack = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    return _operandStack;
}
-(double)popOperand
{
    NSNumber *objectNum = [self.operandStack lastObject];
    if (objectNum)[self.operandStack removeLastObject];
    return [objectNum doubleValue];

}
/*-(void) setOperandStack:(NSMutableArray *)operandStack
{
    _operandStack = operandStack;
}*/

-(void)pushOperand:(double)opernand
{
    [self.operandStack addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:opernand]];

}
-(double)performOperation:(NSString *)operation
{
    double result=0;

    if([operation isEqualToString:@"+"])
    {
        result = self.popOperand + self.popOperand;
    }
    else if ([@"*" isEqualToString:operation])
    {
        result = self.popOperand * self.popOperand;
    }
    [self pushOperand:result];

    return result;
}


@end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whilst the `.` notation is primarily used for properties, it can be used for paramaterless methods that return a value. Why? Because the synthesised getter for a property is in the same form.

```
-(double)calcValue {
    ....
    return value;
}
```

Is equivalent to the property declaration:

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly) double calcValue;
```

Whilst there may be no property declaration, it doesn't mean the `.` notation cannot be used. The compiler will effectively change `.` notation to a method call when compiling, as `.` is a form of *syntactic sugar*. As so:

```
self.popOperand
// Translates to
[self popOperand];
```

This leads on to part 2, why does `[self.pushOperand:result];` not work? The reason being is that `.` does not support the passing of parameters directly.

The only way to assign/push a parameter to a property is via `self.pushOperand = result`, but this wouldn't work, because there isn't a corresponding `- (void)setPushOperand:(double)pushOperand;` that the `.` notation assignment maps to.

`[self pushOperand:result];` works because you're being explicit in calling a particular method, called `pushOperand:`.

Overall, keep `.` notation for properties only, and if you're using a method that isn't designed to be a 'property', be explicit.

**Update:** `self` is a reserved keyword, that represents a pointer to the instance we're working within at that time.

For example, I can create two instances of `Calcbrain` **outside of Calcbrain, for example BrainViewController**:

```
Calcbrain* instance1;
Calcbrain* instance2;
```

Now, `Calcbrain` has methods declared within it, let's use `-(double)performOperation:(NSString *)operation` as an example. Now, if I wanted to call that from BrainViewController, I would do:

```
[instance1 performOperation:@"+"];
[instance2 performOperation:@"+"];
```

Because we are calling a method which is part of another class, I have to determine the correct instance I've created to refer to it (i.e. `instance1` and `instance2`). But how would I call that from within the class itself, and make sure it applies to the correct instance? The instance I've created is unaware of the other instances I've created. Use `self`. `self` allows you to reference yourself within methods. So if I wanted to `performOperation` within `Calcbrain` itself, I would need to use self:

```
[self performOperation:@"+"];
```

Comment: what about `self.display` for example. is display also considered a property? and another question, what's the best way to explain `self` and to what it's referring?

Comment: Yes, `self.display` is a property of whatever class declared it; it is an object that can be considered a property of the class it comes from, it defines some characteristic of that class. In regards to `self`, I will update my answer as it can be difficult to describe in a couple of sentences.

Answer (score 2):

The "dot" is just a [syntactic sugar](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocObjectsClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH11-SW17), it can be used even if there isn't a declared property. The expression

```
a.someProperty
```

is equivalent to

```
[a someProperty]
```

and the expression

```
a.someProperty = c
```

is equivalent to

```
[a setSomeProperty:c]
```

Therefore, `self.popOperand` is just the same as `[self popOperand]`. And one could also use the "dot" in some absurd cases like `[NSMutableArray alloc].init`.

---

Using the "dot"  syntax for non-properties are **highly discouraged**. If I were the maintainer of this code I would change all `self.popOperand` back to `[self popOperand]` to avoid confusion.

(BTW, it is not defined which side of the `+` will get evaluated first. Better change

```
result = [self popOperand] + [self popOperand]
```

to

```
double operand1 = [self popOperand]
double operand2 = [self popOperand]
result = operand1 + operand2;
```

This will be a trouble when you define `-` and `/`.)

Comment: actually this line of code:  `result = [self popOperand] + [self popOperand]` is from the stanford ios course on Itunes U :)

Answer (score 0):

Dot is used to access properties of the class. You can also access properties and methods without dots:

```
[classInstance someMethodOrProperty];
```

This code: `[classInstance someProperty];` equals this code `classInstance.someProperty;` You cannot call methods with dots like properties.